# How to run Hadoop as part of test suite of Spring application?

Tags: spring, hadoop

I would like to set up a simple "Hello, World!" to get an understanding of how to use basic Hadoop functionality such storing/reading files using HDFS.

Is it possible to:

- Run an embedded Hadoop as part of my application?
- Run an embedded Hadoop as part of my tests?

I would like to put together a minimal Spring Boot set up for this. What is the minimal Spring configuration required for this? There are sufficient examples illustrating how to read/write files using HDFS, but I still haven't been able to work out the what I need as Spring configuration. It's a bit hard to figure out what libraries one really needs, as it seems that the Spring Hadoop examples are out of date. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily use Hadoop Filesystem API [1](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.0.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html) [2](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileContext.html) with any local POSIX filesystem without Hadoop cluster.
The Hadoop API is very generic and provides many concrete implementations for different storage systems such as HDFS, S3, Azure Data Lake Store, etc.

You can embed HDFS within your application (i.e run Namenode and Datanodes withing single JVM process), but this is only reasonable for tests.
There is Hadoop Minicluster which you can start from command-line (`CLI MiniCluster`)  [3](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/CLIMiniCluster.html) or via Java API in your unit-tests with `MiniDFSCluster` class [4](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/src/test/java/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/MiniDFSCluster.java) found in `hadoop-minicluster` package.

You can start Mini Cluster with Spring by making a separate configuration for it and using it as `@ContextConfiguration` with your unit tests.

```java
@org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
public class MiniClusterConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = "temp-folder", initMethod = "create", destroyMethod = "delete")
    public TemporaryFolder temporaryFolder() {
        return new TemporaryFolder();
    }

    @Bean
    public Configuration configuration(final TemporaryFolder temporaryFolder) {
        final Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        conf.set(
            MiniDFSCluster.HDFS_MINIDFS_BASEDIR,
            temporaryFolder.getRoot().getAbsolutePath()
        );
        return conf;
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    public MiniDFSCluster cluster(final Configuration conf) throws IOException {
        final MiniDFSCluster cluster = new MiniDFSCluster.Builder(conf)
            .clusterId(String.valueOf(this.hashCode()))
            .build();
        cluster.waitClusterUp();
        return cluster;
    }

    @Bean
    public FileSystem fileSystem(final MiniDFSCluster cluster) throws IOException {
        return cluster.getFileSystem();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public Path temp(final FileSystem fs) throws IOException {
        final Path path = new Path("/tmp", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        fs.mkdirs(path);
        return path;
    }
}
```

You will inject `FileSystem` and a temporary `Path` into your tests, and as I've mentioned above, there's no difference from API stand point in either it's a real cluster, mini-cluster, or local filesystem.  Note that there is a startup cost of this, so you likely want to annotated your tests with `@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)` in order to prevent cluster restart for each test.

In you want this code to run on Windows you will need a compatibility layer called `wintuils` [5](https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils) (which makes possible to access Windows filesystem in a POSIX way).
You have to point environment variable `HADOOP_HOME` to it, and depending on version load its shared library

```java
String HADOOP_HOME = System.getenv("HADOOP_HOME");
System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", HADOOP_HOME);
System.setProperty("hadoop.tmp.dir", System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
final String lib = String.format("%s/lib/hadoop.dll", HADOOP_HOME);
System.load(lib);
```

Comment: Thanks for the example! There seems to be a problem with the `temp` bean. Would you mind correcting it? Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks, fixed that, `@Bean` was missing. You only need temp if you keep your minicluster running between the tests, otherwise just use `/`

Comment: Thanks! For the sake of future developers who come across this, could you please correct the `temporaryFolder` and `temp` beans, because they are not compilable right now? Much appreciated! :)